# Python Error regarding unoderable type

Tags: python

```
  lvl=int(input("Level(1-15) => "))
  val=1 
  list(range(1, 16)) 

  if lvl != list and lvl >= list:
  print("Invalid Input. Please enter an integer value between 1 to 15")
```

Error message:

```
 Level(1-15) => 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
if lvl != list and lvl >= list:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() >= type()
```

Just wondering why its having this sort of error but it works fine without the "and lvl >= list"

Comment: `range(...)` already returns a list. No need to do `list(range(...))`

Comment: You are comparing apples with CDs.. How can you check if a number is bigger than a list?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `list` is no variable (and should not be), because it is a data structure in python. `lvl` is an integer in your case. Do you want to check, whether `lvl` is contained in the list from `1..15`?

Comment: Ohh i see thanks for the help. Didn't really thought about what i was comparing

Comment: @rocksteady The error means OP is using Python 3. [**`range`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) does not return a list in Python 3.

Comment: You are absolutely right. @[peter wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084416/peter-wood)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should actually be written like this:

```
 lvl = int(input("Level(1-15) => "))

 ... 

 if lvl < 1 and lvl >= 16:
   print("Invalid Input. Please enter an integer value between 1 to 15")
```

**Note**: Specifically, regarding why your code seems to "work" when you remove the `and lvl >= list` is actually because `list` is a reserved keyword for the type `list`:

```
 >>> list
 <type 'list'>
```

And so your code naturally errors when you are trying to compare the integer `lvl` and the type `list`.

Comment: If you're answering, I think you should let OP know what mistakes he's doing, like the fact that he didn't even assign the value returned by `list()` to a variable, and why comparison between numbers and lists are not working, and how one could achieve that through `__ge__` magic methods, and so on. Otherwise it's not very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `list` is a datatype. What you're doing wrong is you're essentially trying to see if 5 is greater than books on a bookshelf. You'll want to do:

```
lvl = int(input("Level(1-15) => "))
val = 1 # I don't know why this exists, but okay.

# If the value 'lvl' is not in the range of 1 - 15
if lvl not in range(1, 16): 
    print("Invalid Input. Please enter an integer value between 1 to 15")
```